# Html Button not lowering opacity on hover

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I've been coding HTML and CSS for about a week now and I've spent the past 2 hours stuck on troubleshooting why this button won't get its opacity lowered on hover.

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #DE4642;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "gotham_rounded_bold";
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.button1:hover {
  opacity: 0.6
}
```

```html
<div class="get_started">
  <button class="button1">GET STARTED</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried your code and its working for me? What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. That's only part of the HTML and CSS though. I figured I would only include the part relating to the button. It's my first time posting on here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is your code working on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezn01p2j/ -- must be conflicting with some other code you have. Mind sharing more css so we can see what its conflicting with?

Comment: @JCBiggar Hers the CSS https://www.codepile.net/pile/bLrO2rPo

Comment: Just tried that code too, and it seems to be just fine. You are doing everything right with css. Do you have another stylesheet attached or <style> in the head section of your html?

Comment: so I think I just figured it out. I added z-index: 1 to the css and fixed it. I think it was because it was under some text somehow but visually it wasn't. How do I avoid this in the future? @JCBiggar

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out! and there really isn't a single answer to that, as you code more, you'll get better and better at knowing how to write your code, and being able to solve problems much quicker!.... The built in Inspect Element feature in Chrome is extremely useful for trouble shooting, incase you haven't used that yet.